# Time Complexity of Rotating Matrix 90 degrees

Tags: time-complexity

In my textbook, the time complexity is O(n^2). Wouldn't it actually be quicker than n^2 since the first loop has a bound of n/2 and the second loop a bound of n-1-layer; so for both loops it is not hitting all of n?

```
for (int layer = 0; layer < n / 2; layer++) {
    int first = layer;
    int last = n - 1 - layer;
    for(int i = first; i < last; i++) {
        int offset = i - first;
        int top = matrix[first][i]; // save top

        // left -> top
        matrix[first][i] = matrix[last-offset][first];          

        // bottom -> left
        matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix[last][last - offset]; 

        // right -> bottom
        matrix[last][last - offset] = matrix[i][last]; 

        // top -> right
        matrix[i][last] = top; // right <- saved top
    }
}
```

Comment: Constant multipliers and dividers are ignored in complexity analysis since they are insignificant as n grows significantly large. ```O(n^2/2) = O(n^2)``` Unless your divider IS NOT a constant and changes with your input (see logarithmic and exponential functions), you can ignore such terms. You should take a look at what ```BigO``` actually means

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the above code:

```
// Constant divisors or multipliers does not have any effect on time complexity
O((n/2)*(n/2)) ==> O((n^2)/4) ==> O(n^2)
```